# Creating Bitmaps from ARGB strings (in actionscript-3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, arrays, rgb, bitmapdata

in actionscript 3, what's the fastest way to dump your data (not from a file) into a bitmap for display?

I have it working with setPixels and colored rects but that's way too slow/inefficient.

Is there a way to load in the raw bytes or hijack the loader class to put in custom loader data?

What would be the best/fastest--should I start writing a byte encoder?

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly copy data from a [ByteArray](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) into a [Bitmap](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) using [setPixels()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#setPixels()). Even if you need to do some wrangling of your data beforehand, it should be way faster than setting each pixel individually.

Comment: I'm already doing that and it works pretty good with fillrect. I'm wondering if there is an alternative that is faster.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to go with something similar to base64 like I originally thought.

Thanks for the help anyways.